# How do I debug an MPI program?

Tags: debugging, mpi

I have an MPI program which compiles and runs, but I would like to step through it to make sure nothing bizarre is happening. Ideally, I would like a simple way to attach GDB to any particular process, but I'm not really sure whether that's possible or how to do it. An alternative would be having each process write debug output to a separate log file, but this doesn't really give the same freedom as a debugger.

Are there better approaches? How do you debug MPI programs?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As someone else said, [TotalView](https://www.roguewave.com/products-services/totalview) is the standard for this.  But it will cost you an arm and a leg.

The OpenMPI site has a great [FAQ on MPI debugging](http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging).  Item #6 in the FAQ describes how to attach GDB to MPI processes.  Read the whole thing, there are some great tips.

If you find that you have far too many processes to keep track of, though, check out [Stack Trace Analysis Tool (STAT)](http://www.paradyn.org/STAT/).  We use this at Livermore to collect stack traces from potentially hundreds of thousands of running processes and to represent them intelligently to users.  It's not a full-featured debugger (a full-featured debugger would never scale to 208k cores), but it will tell you which groups of processes are doing the same thing.  You can then step through a representative from each group in a standard debugger.

Comment: As of 2010 [Allinea DDT](http://www.olcf.ornl.gov/2010/07/12/upgrade-adds-muscle-to-debugger/) is a full-featured debugger that scales to over 208k cores

Comment: So I'll go ahead and upvote @Mark's answer here.  DDT is nice.  Try it out too.  TotalView also integrates with STAT now, so if your site has a TotalView installation you could try that as well.  LLNL keeps TotalView and DDT around, and it's nice that TotalView finally has some stiff competition.

Comment: I'd like to second the link to FAQ on MPI debugging (http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers). Specifically, bullet 6 is a good, quick, and easy (enough for even me!) to understand way to at least debug an individual process.

Comment: The steps in #6 of the FAQ page worked excellently for me and helped me figure out my problem. Thanks so much for this.

Answer (score 103):

I have found gdb quite useful. I use it as

```
mpirun -np <NP> xterm -e gdb ./program
```

This the launches  xterm windows in which I can do

```
run <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>
```

usually works fine

You can also package these commands together using:

```
mpirun -n <NP> xterm -hold -e gdb -ex run --args ./program [arg1] [arg2] [...]
```

Comment: How can I send the same input to the all NP gdb xterms? For example, I want to add two breakpoints to every process, and there are 16 processes. Is there some alternative to xterm to do this? Can we connect sessions into single instance of screen, tmux, or Chris Jones's Terminator?

Comment: @osgx You can do this by saving the commands ("break xxx", "break yyy", "run") to `<file>` and passing `-x <file>` to gdb.

Comment: but I meet an error, the error message is " execvp error on file xterm (No such file or directory) "

Comment: when I try this with jdb & OpenMPI it doesn't work, i.e. each jdb instance sees num_ranks of 1 instead of what's given to -np argument. any idea why?

Comment: Using the TMPI script  is also a nice approach: https://github.com/Azrael3000/tmpi

Answer (score 36):

Many of the posts here are about GDB, but don't mention how to attach to a process from startup. Obviously, you can attach to all processes:

```
mpiexec -n X gdb ./a.out
```

But that is wildly ineffective since you'll have to bounce around to start up all of your processes. If you just want to debug one (or a small number of) MPI process, you can add that as a separate executable on the command line using the `:` operator:

```
mpiexec -n 1 gdb ./a.out : -n X-1 ./a.out
```

Now only one of your processes will get GDB.

Comment: I can use "mpiexec -n X gdb ./a.out", but is there any way to use gdb -tui mode?

Answer (score 18):

As others have mentioned, if you're only working with a *handful* of MPI processes you can try to use [multiple gdb sessions](https://web.archive.org/web/20130818090310/http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/UserInfo/Resources/Hardware/CommonDoc/mpich2_gdb.html), the redoubtable [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mpiwrap) or roll your own printf / logging solution.

If you're using more processes than that, you really start needing a proper debugger. The [OpenMPI FAQ](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging) recommends both [Allinea DDT](https://www.arm.com/products/development-tools/server-and-hpc/forge) and [TotalView](https://web.archive.org/web/20141019045820/http://www.roguewave.com:80/products/totalview.aspx).

I work on [Allinea DDT](https://www.arm.com/products/development-tools/server-and-hpc/forge). It's a full-featured, graphical source-code debugger so yes, you can:

- Debug or attach to (over 200k) MPI processes
- Step and pause them in groups or individually
- Add breakpoints, watches and tracepoints
- Catch memory errors and leaks

...and so on. If you've used Eclipse or Visual Studio then you'll be right at home.

We added some interesting features specifically for debugging *parallel* code (be it MPI, multi-threaded or CUDA):

- Scalar variables are automatically compared across all processes:
  [image: Sparklines showing values across processes]
  <sub>(source: [allinea.com](https://www.allinea.com/Portals/90122/images/features/unusual-data-values-original.png))</sub>
- You can also trace and filter the values of variables and expressions over processes and time:
  [image: Tracepoints log values over time]

It's widely used amongst [top500](https://www.top500.org/list/2011/11/100/) HPC sites, such as [ORNL](https://web.archive.org/web/20121102135750/http://www.olcf.ornl.gov:80/2010/07/12/upgrade-adds-muscle-to-debugger/), [NCSA](https://web.archive.org/web/20120822175534/http://www.hpcwire.com/hpcwire/2012-05-14/blue_waters_supercomputer_debugs_with_allinea_ddt.html), [LLNL](https://computing.llnl.gov/?set=code&page=index#debugging_tools), [Jülich](https://www.fz-juelich.de/ias/jsc/EN/Expertise/Supercomputers/JUGENE/UserInfo/ParallelDebugging.html#doc1096938bodyText6) et. al.

The interface is pretty snappy; we timed stepping and merging the stacks and variables of 220,000 processes at 0.1s as part of the acceptance testing on Oak Ridge's Jaguar cluster.

@tgamblin mentioned the excellent [STAT](http://www.paradyn.org/STAT/), which integrates with [Allinea DDT](https://www.arm.com/products/development-tools/server-and-hpc/forge), as do several other popular open source projects.

Answer (score 8):

http://valgrind.org/ nuf said

---

More specific link: [Debugging MPI Parallel Programs with Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mpiwrap)

Comment: Valgrind is not the same as an interactive debugger, but it is nice to know it works with MPI.

Answer (score 8):

If you are a `tmux` user you will feel very comfortable using the script of **Benedikt Morbach**: `tmpi`

Original source: <del>https://github.com/moben/scripts/blob/master/tmpi</del>

Fork: https://github.com/Azrael3000/tmpi

With it you have multiple panels (number of processes) all synchronized (every command is copied on all panels or processes at the same time so you save lot of time comparing with the `xterm -e` approach). Moreover you can know the variables' values in the process you want just doing a `print` without having to move to another panel, this will print on each panel the values of the variable for each process.

If you are not a `tmux` user I recommend strongly to try it and see.

Comment: Since tmpi is really fantastic and exactly what I was looking for, I forked it on my github account: https://github.com/Azrael3000/tmpi since the original author removed it

Answer (score 6):

http://github.com/jimktrains/pgdb/tree/master is a utility I wrote to do this very thing.  There are some docs and feel free to pm me for questions.

You basically call a perl program that wraps GDB and funnels it's IO to a central server.  This allows GDB to be running on each host and for you to access it on each host at the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check this out next time I'm working in MPI.

Answer (score 5):

Using `screen` together with `gdb` to debug MPI applications works nicely, especially if `xterm` is unavailable or you're dealing with more than a few processors. There were many pitfalls along the way with accompanying stackoverflow searches, so I'll reproduce my solution in full.

First, add code after MPI_Init to print out the PID and halt the program to wait for you to attach. The standard solution seems to be an infinite loop; I eventually settled on `raise(SIGSTOP);`, which requires an extra call of `continue` to escape within gdb.

```
}
    int i, id, nid;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&id);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nid);
    for (i=0; i<nid; i++) {
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if (i==id) {
            fprintf(stderr,"PID %d rank %d\n",getpid(),id);
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    raise(SIGSTOP);
}
```

After compiling, run the executable in the background, and catch the stderr. You can then `grep` the stderr file for some keyword (here literal PID) to get the PID and rank of each process.

```
MDRUN_EXE=../../Your/Path/To/bin/executable
MDRUN_ARG="-a arg1 -f file1 -e etc"

mpiexec -n 1 $MDRUN_EXE $MDRUN_ARG >> output 2>> error &

sleep 2

PIDFILE=pid.dat
grep PID error > $PIDFILE
PIDs=(`awk '{print $2}' $PIDFILE`)
RANKs=(`awk '{print $4}' $PIDFILE`)
```

A gdb session can be attached to each process with `gdb $MDRUN_EXE $PID`. Doing so within a screen session allows easy access to any gdb session. `-d -m` starts the screen in detached mode, `-S "P$RANK"` allows you to name the screen for easy access later, and the `-l` option to bash starts it in interactive mode and keeps gdb from exiting immediately.

```
for i in `awk 'BEGIN {for (i=0;i<'${#PIDs[@]}';i++) {print i}}'`
do
    PID=${PIDs[$i]}
    RANK=${RANKs[$i]}
    screen -d -m -S "P$RANK" bash -l -c "gdb $MDRUN_EXE $PID"
done
```

Once gdb has started in the screens, you may script input to the screens (so that you don't have to enter every screen and type the same thing) using screen's `-X stuff` command. A newline is required at the end of the command. Here the screens are accessed by `-S "P$i"` using the names previously given. The `-p 0` option is critical, otherwise the command intermittently fails (based on whether or not you have previously attached to the screen).

```
for i in `awk 'BEGIN {for (i=0;i<'${#PIDs[@]}';i++) {print i}}'`
do
    screen -S "P$i" -p 0 -X stuff "set logging file debug.$i.log
"
    screen -S "P$i" -p 0 -X stuff "set logging overwrite on
"
    screen -S "P$i" -p 0 -X stuff "set logging on
"
    screen -S "P$i" -p 0 -X stuff "source debug.init
"
done
```

At this point you can attach to any screen using `screen -rS "P$i"` and detach using `Ctrl+A+D`. Commands may be sent to all gdb sessions in analogy with the previous section of code.

Answer (score 3):

The "standard" way to debug MPI programs is by using a debugger which supports that execution model.

On UNIX, [TotalView](http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview.aspx) is said to have good suppoort for MPI.

Answer (score 3):

I use this little homebrewn method to attach debugger to MPI processes - call the following function, DebugWait(), right after MPI_Init() in your code. Now while the processes are waiting for keyboard input, you have all the time to attach the debugger to them and add breakpoints. When you are done, provide a single character input and you are ready to go.

```
static void DebugWait(int rank) {
    char    a;

    if(rank == 0) {
        scanf("%c", &a);
        printf("%d: Starting now\n", rank);
    } 

    MPI_Bcast(&a, 1, MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("%d: Starting now\n", rank);
}
```

Of course you would want to compile this function for debug builds only.

Comment: MPI has required the most debug statements I have ever written for even simple code. (lol) This can be very helpful.

Comment: This solution is similar to bullet 6 here (http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers). You can improve your code a little by adding `gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)); printf("PID %d on host %s ready for attach\n", getpid(), hostname);`. Then, you attach to the process by typing `rsh <hostname_from_print_statement>`, and finally `gdb --pid=<PID_from_print_statement>`.

Answer (score 3):

There is also my open-source tool, padb, which aims to help with parallel programming.  I call it a "Job Inspection Tool" as it functions not only as a debugger can also function for example as a parallel top like program.  Run in "Full Report" mode it'll show you stack traces of every process within your application along with local variables for every function over every rank (assuming you compiled with -g).  It'll also show you the "MPI message queues", that is the list of outstanding sends and receives for each rank within the job.

As well as showing the full report it's also possible to tell padb to zoom in on individual bits of information within the job, there are a myriad of options and configuration items to control what information is shown, see the web page for more details.

[Padb](http://padb.pittman.org.uk/full-report.html)

Answer (score 3):

I've written an extension to gdb called [MPIGDB](https://github.com/robertu94/mpigdb/) written in Rust that greatly simplifies debugging MPI programs.  It adds extension commands to GDB to simplify working with multiple processes.

```
mpigdb -np 4 -- ./program arg1 arg2
```

Unlike some of the prior examples, it runs in a single gdb instance making it much easier to control multiple mpi ranks simultaneously, and I've used it upto 128 processes, but it works best with 64 or less.  Here is a demo of it in action [image: demo of it in action]

Answer (score 2):

The command to attach gdb to an mpi process is incomplete, it should be

```
mpirun -np <NP> xterm -e gdb ./program
```

A brief discussion of mpi and gdb can be found [here](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/mpich-discuss/2010-April/006966.html)

Answer (score 2):

Quite a simple way to debug an MPI program.

In main () function add sleep (some_seconds)

Run the program as usual

```
$ mpirun -np <num_of_proc> <prog> <prog_args>
```

Program will start and get into the sleep.

So you will have some seconds to find you processes by ps, run gdb and attach to them.

If you use some editor like QtCreator you can use

*Debug->Start debugging->Attach to running application*

and find you processes there.

Answer (score 1):

I do some MPI-related debugging with log traces, but you can also run gdb if you're using mpich2: [MPICH2 and gdb](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/pardebug.html). This technique is a good practice in general when you're dealing with a process that's tricky to launch from a debugger.

Comment: Changed to another link that isn't broken, added some commentary.

Answer (score 1):

`mpirun -gdb`

Thanks to http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/UserInfo/Resources/Hardware/CommonDoc/mpich2_gdb.html ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130818090310/http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/UserInfo/Resources/Hardware/CommonDoc/mpich2_gdb.html))

Comment: This does not work in recent MPICH versions, though it does work with Intel MPI.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to run your code within SMPI, the simulated MPI. That's an open source project in which I'm involved. Every MPI rank will be converted into threads of the same UNIX process. You can then easily use gdb to step the MPI ranks.

SMPI proposes other advantages to the study of MPI applications: clairevoyance (you can observe every parts of the system), reproducibility (several runs lead to the exact same behavior unless you specify so), absence of heisenbugs (as the simulated platform is kept different from the host one), etc.

For more information, see [this presentation](http://simgrid.gforge.inria.fr/tutorials/simgrid-smpi-101.pdf), or that [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299147/running-mpi-code-in-my-laptop).

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual studio code which is free and much easier to work with than `xterm`. You duplicate the VS Code window and attach the debugger manually to each process. See the instruction in the below video:

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTt02xuD51w)

Answer (score 0):

I released `mpitx` ([s417-lama/mpitx](https://github.com/s417-lama/mpitx)), which was inspired by the great usage of tmux in `tmpi`, but it supports **multi-node execution** with minimal dependencies (only Python3 and tmux).

Launch `gdb` on (possibly distributed) 4 nodes with:

```
mpitx -n 4 -- gdb --args ./program arg1 arg2 ...
```

As well as `tmpi`, you can allocate a tmux pane for each MPI process and duplicate keyboard input to all MPI processes.
It really helps debugging and also checking the machine status on multiple nodes at the same time.

Please check the [GitHub website](https://github.com/s417-lama/mpitx) to see working examples.