# Optimal Way to Send Recv to multiple processes in MPI

Tags: c++, debugging, parallel-processing, mpi

My specific problem is as follows:
Say I have 4 workers and 1 master process. I want to send messages from each worker to all other workers. (from worker 1 to 2,3,4; from process 2 to 1,3,4, etc.)

I don't care about the order at which messages are sent, but I care about performance. The data I am sending is very big, could be in the gigabytes.

I am currently using Isend and Recv, but kept getting segmentation faults. I tried to use Sendrecv, but that ones seems to just hang in the middle, possibly due to deadlock. So I am wondering what is the best way to send and receive to and from multiple processes.

Here is my current code:

```
for(int id  = 1; id < num_processes; id++) { 
    // Some computation with the vector vec //
    MPI_Request request;
    if(id != myId)
        MPI_Isend(&vec.front(), vec.size(), mpi_bid, id, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
}
```

Then for receiving.

```
for(int id = 1; id < num_processes; id++) {
    MPI_Request request2;
    if(id != myID)
        MPI_Recv(&recvVec.front(), some_large_value, mpi_bid, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request2);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The data pattern you describe is MPI_Alltoall or MPI_Alltoallv.  Why are you not using that collective for this operation?

Comment: Thanks! Does it work if my vector to be sent has different lengths? Seems that alltoall sends same length for all processes.

Comment: `MPI_Alltoallv` is to be used with vectors of varying size. Note also that the last argument of `MPI_Recv` is of type `MPI_Status` and not `MPI_Request`. Perhaps you meant to use `MPI_Irecv` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting segfaults, you issue is probably something other than doing your data transfer optimally. You're probably having an issue somewhere else too. You might want to try a debugger to figure out what's going on. You can see the big post about MPI debugging here ([How do I debug an MPI program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329259/how-do-i-debug-an-mpi-program/17881783#17881783)). If you specifically want a free debugger, you can always use GDB (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17881783/491687) if you don't know how to do that).