# Seeing the code being executed for an MPI program

Tags: mpi, step-into

I want to step through and SEE the code that is being executed in an `MPI` program. For example if `MPI_Init()` is being executed then I should be able to SEE what code is actually being executed - like going into the *mpi.h* file and seeing statements there, maybe going into another *xyz.c* file and seeing the part of the code being executed there. This is analogous to the *F7* key we had with *Turbo C++* which helped us to see and execute one line at a time. Is *TotalView* a software which lets us do this ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, TotalView, which is a debugger, is such a software.  Another such tool is DDT (http://www.allinea.com/products/ddt/).  If you like pain you can even attach multiple instances of `gdb` (or whatever your favourite serial debugger might be) to the multiple MPI processes that execute when your program runs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug an MPI program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329259/how-do-i-debug-an-mpi-program)

Comment: There are many options for debugging an MPI program. Take a look at the question in the comment above to find lots of options.