# How to make sure that there are no active transfers in MPI program?

Tags: debugging, mpi

I have a MPI program which most likely has a bug that causes sends and receives to get out of sync somewhere. As a consequence, the data which a process receives is not the one the other processes send. Since I don't want to lose an arm and a leg to buy [TotalView or Allinea DDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329259/how-do-i-debug-an-mpi-program), I was wondering whether it is possible to determine the number of "in flight" transfers or bytes using plain MPI so that it can be printed to the terminal. (I have a few locations where this number is supposed to be zero.)

I've already tried `MPI_Get_count()` but that seems to be specific to a single transfer instead of returning the *total* number of bytes received. Also, `MPI_Barrier()` does not help in my case because my processes reach the same code location but the received data is still out-of sync.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend heavily on which implementation you're using, but the `MPIT` interface may be what you want. It exposes lots of performance variables that you can use to query the system about internal state. I'm not an expert on `MPIT`, but my understanding is that the variables exposed are specific to the implementation.