# Can't run simple mpi program

Tags: c++, mpi, intel-mpi

I recently installed Intel's Cluster Studio, and was testing IMPI. When I try running a simple hello world program using `mpirun`, the process takes forever, and I have to end it myself. I used the following code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MPI::Init(argc, argv);

  int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
  int size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();

  std::cout << "Returned: " << system("sleep 2") << " ";
  std::cout << "Hello World! I am " << rank << " of " << size <<
          std::endl;

  MPI::Finalize();
  return (0);
}
```

I compiled it with `mpiicpc main.cpp -o main`. 
This is the output when I added `-show` option:

```
icpc main.cpp -o main -I/opt/intel/impi/4.1.1.036/intel64/include -L/opt/intel/impi/4.1.1.036/intel64/lib -Xlinker --enable-new-dtags -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/impi/4.1.1.036/intel64/lib -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /opt/intel/mpi-rt/4.1 -lmpigc4 -lmpigf -lmpi -lmpigi -ldl -lrt -lpthread
```

I ran the executable with `mpirun -np 4 main`.

Additional info:

```
$which mpirun 
/opt/intel/impi/4.1.1.036/intel64/bin/mpirun

$mpiicpc --version
icpc (ICC) 14.0.0 20130728
```

**UPDATE**:
I also tried compiling it using `g++` instead of `icpc`. No luck. My guess is there is a problem with the MPI runtime, but I can't find it. Debugging didn't work. I think the program is not initializing in the first place.

Comment: Can you throw on a debugger to tell us where it's hanging? `Init`? `Finalize`? Afterward?

Comment: Can you walk me through the debugging? I'm a total noob regarding MPI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329259/how-do-i-debug-an-mpi-program

Comment: This code works fine with openmpi 1.4.3. Could you try to remove the call to `system()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is still interested, I found out what was wrong. According to this [link](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ics/ics2013/ics_tutorial/Linux_mpi.htm), Unlike some other MPI implementations, `Intel MPI Library uses a Multi-Purpose Daemon (MPD) job startup mechanism. To run programs compiled with mpicc (or related) commands, you must first set up MPD daemons.` So, I followed the steps explained in the link, executed the `mpdboot`command, and voilà, It works finally.