# Debugging MPI Remotely Using GDB

Tags: c, debugging, raspberry-pi, gdb, mpi

I am trying to debug code I wrote using MPI from a remote access group of pi's. I can not access the Pis directly in order to be able to use a GUI to debug the code.

I have tried what using screen like is shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644046/use-gdb-to-debug-mpi-in-multiple-screen-windows/32655577#32655577) but anytime I try to use screen
 I get this message:

```
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 2 slots
that were requested by the application:
  screen

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots available
for use.
```

If I try and tell it to just use 1 screen, mpiexec fails

```
mpiexec -N 16 --host 10.0.0.3 -np 1 screen -oversubscribe batSRTest3 shortpass.bat
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.

NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpiexec command
      line parameter option (remember that mpiexec interprets the first
      unrecognized command line token as the executable).

Node:       node1
Executable: screen
```

I have looked at the openMPI FAQ but the information does not apply for remote access. I tried following [this](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers) part but when I type in

```
gdb --pid
```

with the code running nothing happens. Method 2 in that section also will not work as I cannot open multiple windows when accessing the PIs using Putty.

I want to be able to debug it when running on all of the nodes ideally, and currently to run my program I have to use:

```
$ mpiexec -N 4 --host 10.0.0.3,10.0.0.4,10.0.0.5,10.0.0.6 -oversubscribe batSRTest shortpass.bat
```

Which is also causing confusion as I'm not even sure I am adding in the extra arguments correctly.

I did try debugging using gdb similiar to the answer shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876357/determine-the-line-of-code-that-causes-a-segmentation-fault) but that just resulted in MPI failing since it wasn't given multiple tasks.

```
(gdb) exec-file batSRTest3
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/progs/batSRTest3 mpiexec -N 16 --host 10.0.0.3 -oversubscribe batSRTest3 shortpass.bat
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[Detaching after fork from child process 17157]
[New Thread 0x7691a460 (LWP 17162)]
[New Thread 0x75d3d460 (LWP 17163)]
[node1:17153] *** An error occurred in MPI_Group_incl
[node1:17153] *** reported by process [141361153,0]
[node1:17153] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[node1:17153] *** MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank
[node1:17153] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[node1:17153] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[Thread 0x7691a460 (LWP 17162) exited]
[Thread 0x76ff5010 (LWP 17153) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 17153) exited with code 06]
(gdb) q
```

Comment: If you can SSH into the Pi and it has at least some X terminal emulator installed, you can run GDB in multiple terminals with something like `mpirun -np 4 xterm -e gdb -ex=run --args batSRTest shortpass.bat`. This should start 4 X terminals with `gdb` running your program in each of them. If any MPI rank crashes, its `gdb` parent will take control. This requires setting up X11 forwarding over SSH or an X11 server listening on an IP that the Pi can connect to. In the latter case, you have to set `DISPLAY` accordingly.

Comment: @HristoIliev I tried running it and it fails to start with an error of mpirun being unable to find  the executable xterm. So for some reason it doesn't recognize xterm as a command line token.

Comment: @HristoIliev As for the X11 server stuff, I do not have control over any of it. I am doing research for my graduate degree and my adviser is the one in charge of all the server side stuff as the pis are connected to his server. However, I may be able to get him to set it up if you can tell me what needs to be set up. Will just asking for x11 forwarding over SSH be enough for him to know what I need? I have 0 experience with server side stuff as I'm an engineering major and not a CS major.

Comment: First of all, unless there are very ARM-specific parts in it, have you tried running and debugging your MPI program on a PC?

Comment: @HristoIliev I can not run it on my pc as I need to debug it on multiple nodes

Comment: If your program cannot run correctly on a single node, I would create a number of virtual machines.

Comment: My PC is not set up to be able to run virtual machines. It would be faster to redo all of my code than it would be to set everything up and learn how to make MPI work across virtual machines. Additionally, the errors I am getting are unlikely to occur on my PC as I do not have limited space on it unlike the pis. I need to debug the code on the pi cluster, and not on my PC

Comment: I see. Since Stack Overflow doesn't allow for long and properly formatted comments, let me write one as an answer and I'll try to explain what needs to be done to be able to debug your MPI code with `gdb` under Open MPI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with debugging MPI applications is that they run in the form of multiple process and often you do not have direct access to those processes. Therefore, special parallel debuggers exist that are able to integrate themselves inside the MPI job. The two most popular ones are TotalView and Arm DDT (formerly known as Allinea DDT). Both are **expensive** commercial products, but many academic institutions buy licenses, so check if that is the case with yours. The poor man's solution is to use GDB, which is not a parallel debugger per se, so one has to get creative.

In a nutshell, the idea is to launch your MPI processes under GDB's supervision. But first, let's look at how Open MPI executes a job on multiple nodes. The following diagram should illustrate it:

```
mpiexec <--+--> orted on node1 <--+--> rank 0
           |                      |
           |                      +--- rank 1
           |                      :
           |                      +--- rank N-1
           |
           +--- orted on node2 <--+--- rank N
           |                      |
           |                      +--- rank N+1
           |                      :
           :                      +--- rank 2N-1
```

`mpiexec` is the MPI program launcher, which is responsible for reading in information such as the number of MPI ranks, host lists, binding policy, etc., and using that information to launch the job. For processes on the same host as the one where `mpiexec` was executed, it simply spawns the executable a number of times. For processes on remote nodes, it uses RSH, SSH, or some other mechanism (`srun` for SLURM, TM2, etc.) to start on each remote host the `orted` helper program, which then spawns as many ranks on its particular host as necessary.

Unlike regular Unix programs, you never interact directly with the MPI processes through the console or via Unix signals. Instead, the MPI runtime provides mechanisms for I/O forwarding and signal propagation. You interract with the standard input and output of `mpiexec`, which then uses some infrastructure to send your input to rank 0 and to show you the output received from all ranks. Similarly, signals sent to `mpiexec` are translated and propagated to the MPI ranks. Neither I/O redirection nor signal propagation are fully specified in the MPI standard, because they are very platform-specific, but the general cluster implementation consensus is that the standard output of all ranks gets forwarded to the standard output of `mpiexec` while only rank 0 receives from the standard input; the rest of the ranks have their standard input connected to `/dev/null`. This is shown with directed arrows on the diagram above. Actually, Open MPI allows you to select which rank will receive the standard input by passing `--stdin rank` to `mpiexec`.

If you do `gdb mpiexec ...`, you are not debugging the MPI application. Instead, you will be debugging the MPI launcher itself, which isn't running your code. You need to interpose GDB between the MPI runtime and the MPI ranks themselves, i.e., the above diagram should transform into:

```
mpiexec <--+--> orted on node1 <--+--> gdb <---> rank 0
           |                      |
           |                      +--- gdb <---> rank 1
           |                      :
           |                      +--- gdb <---> rank N-1
           |
           +--- orted on node2 <--+--- gdb <---> rank N
           |                      |
           |                      +--- gdb <---> rank N+1
           |                      :
           :                      +--- gdb <---> rank 2N-1
```

The problem now becomes how to interact with that multitude of GDB instances, mostly because you can directly talk to only one of them. With TotalView and DDT, there is a GUI that talks to the debugger components using network sockets, so this problem is solved. With many GDBs, you have a couple of options (or rather, hacks).

First option is to only debug a single misbehaving MPI rank. If the error always occurs in one and the same rank, you can have it run under the control of GDB while the rest run on their own and then use `--stdin rank` to tell `mpiexec` to let you interact with the debugger if the rank is not 0. You need a simple wrapper script (called `debug_rank.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: debug_rank.sh <rank to debug> <executable> <arguments>

DEBUG_RANK=$1
shift
if [ $OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK == $DEBUG_RANK ]; then
   exec gdb -ex=run --args $*
else
   exec $*
fi
```

The `-ex=run` tells GDB to automatically execute the `run` command after loading the executable. You may omit it if you need to set breakpoints first. Use the wrapper like this, for example to debug rank 3:

```
$ mpiexec ... --stdin 3 ./debug_rank.sh 3 batSRTest shortpass.bat
```

Once rank 3 does something bad or reaches a breakpoint, you'll be dropped into the GDB command prompt. You can also go without the wrapper script and run `gdb` directly, hoping that it won't drop into its command prompt on any other rank than the one you expect to be debugging. If that happens, GDB will exit because its standard input will be connected to `/dev/null`, bringing down the whole MPI job because `mpiexec` will notice one rank exiting without calling `MPI_Finalize()`.

If you don't know which particular rank misbehaves, or if it varies from run to run, or if you want to set breakpoints in more than one of them, then you need to get around the input redirection problem. And the "simplest" solution is to use X11 terminal emulators such as `xterm`. The trick here is that GUI programs get their input from the windowing system and not from the standard input, so you can happily type in and send input to commands running inside `xterm` despite its standard input being connected to `/dev/null`. Also, X11 is a client/server protocol that can run over TCP/IP, allowing you to run `xterm` remotely and have it displayed on your local system when running some X11 implementation such as X.org or XWayland. That's exactly what the command shown on the Open MPI page does:

```
$ mpiexec ... xterm -e gdb -ex=run --args batSRTest shortpass.bat
```

This starts many copies of `xterm` and each copy executes `gdb -ex=run --args batSRTest shortpass.bat`. So you get many instances of GDB in their own terminal windows, which allows you to interact with any and all of them. For this to work, you need a couple of things:

- there should be a copy of `xterm` installed on each Pi
- your network should be a low-latency one because the X11 protocol runs terribly slow on networks with longer delays
- your X11 server should be reachable from all of the Pis and should be configured to accept connections from them
- the `DISPLAY` environment variable should be set accordingly

Any X11 client application such as `xterm` uses the value in the `DISPLAY` environment variable to determine how to connect to the X11 server. Its value has the general form `<optional hostname>:<display>[.<screen>]`. For local servers managing a single display, `DISPLAY` is usually `:0.0` or even just `:0`. When `<optional hostname>` is missing, the special value `host/unix` is implied, which means that the X11 server is listening on a Unix domain socket located in `/tmp/.X11-unix/`. By default, for security reasons X11 servers only listen on Unix domain sockets, which makes them unreachable for network clients. You need to enable listening on a TCP/IP socket and override the bind address, which is `127.0.0.1` by default, and to make sure your host is reachable from the Pis, i.e., that they can directly connect to your IP address on the TCP port that the X11 server listens on. If you go this way, then it works like this:

1. Enable TCP connections for X11 and make it listen on a networked interface
2. Examine the value of `DISPLAY` on your system
3. Prepend your IP address
4. Run the MPI job like this:

`$ mpiexec ... -x DISPLAY=your.ip:d.s xterm -e gdb -ex=run --args batSRTest shortpass.bat`

where `d.s` are the display and screen values that your local `DISPLAY` variable is set to. Make sure your firewall allows inbound TCP connections on port `6000+d`.

Enabling TCP connections from the network is not always advisable or even possible, especially if you are behind NAT. Therefore, an alternative solution is to use X11 forwarding over SSH. For that, you need to pass `-X` or `-Y` to the SSH client when connecting to the SSH server:

```
 $ ssh -X username@server
```

`-Y` instead of `-X` enables some untrusted extensions and may be required for some X11 applications. X11 forwarding only works if enabled on the server side. It also needs that `xauth` is installed on the server. But simply enabling X11 forwarding on the server is not enough since by default the SSH server will listen on the loopback interface for X11 connections to forward. For OpenSSH, the following two configuration parameters must be set accordingly:

```
X11Forwarding yes    # Enable X11 forwarding
X11UseLocalhost no   # Listen on all network interfaces
```

If the SSH server is configured correctly and the `xauth` command is present, when you SSH into the system the value of `DISPLAY` should be something like `hostname:10.0` and running `netstat -an | grep 6010` should produce something like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6010            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6010                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

indicating that the X11 forwarding sockets are bound to all network interfaces. You should then launch the MPI job like this:

```
$ mpiexec -x DISPLAY=server.ip:10.0 xterm -e gdb -ex=run --args batSRTest shortpass.bat
```

where `server.ip` is the IP the server has in the network that connects it to the Pis (I suspect that would be `10.0.0.1` in your case). Also, a range of TCP ports starting with `6010` should be enabled in the server's firewall. The actual value depends on how many X11 forwarding sessions there are. By default, `X11DisplayOffset` is set to `10`, so the SSH server will start with display `10` and go up until an unallocated display number is found. Also, if your home directory on the Pis is not somehow shared with that on the server (e.g., via NFS mounts), you also need to copy the `.Xauthority` file found in your home directory on the server to your home directory on all Pis. This file contains the MIT magic cookie needed to authenticate with the X11 forwarder and is regenerated each time you SSH into the server with X11 forwarding enabled, so make sure to copy it again to all Pis after each SSH login.

Now, if all this is seems overly complex, GDB also has remote debugging abilities. You can start GDB on the server and then run remote MPI processes under the supervision of the GDB server program `gdbserver`, then use the remote debugging commands in the local GDB to connect to one of the GDB servers. This is quite cumbersome. You need to tell each GDB server to listen on a different port. A wrapper script (`debug_server.sh`) may help:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: debug_server.sh <executable> <arguments>

GDB_HOST=$(hostname)
GDB_PORT=$(( 60000 + $OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK ))
echo "GDB server for rank $OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK available on $GDB_HOST:$GDB_PORT"
exec gdbserver :$GDB_PORT $*
```

Run like this:

```
$ mpiexec ... ./debug_server.sh batSRTest shortpass.bat
```

It will print the list of hostnames and ports that the different GDB server instances are listening on. Fire GDB with no arguments and issue the following command:

```
(gdb) target remote hostname:port
```

where `hostname` and `port` are the IP (or hostname, if resolvable) of the Pi of interest. GDB server automatically breaks on the entry point of the executable, which will most likely be somewhere in the dynamic linker, and you need to issue the `continue` command to make it run. You need to do that for each GDB server instance and I don't know a way to disconnect from the current target without stoping it, so you may need to start a load of GDBs too.

There may be some GUI to GDB that simplifies this. You may look into the [Eclipse PTP](https://www.eclipse.org/ptp/) project, which provides a parallel debugger, and see whether it works for you. You may find [these slides](https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/cd/Eclipse-ptp-XSEDE15-complete.pdf) useful. I personally have never used PTP and have no idea what it can do.

---

That's basically why most MPI debugging is done using `printf()` except for the most convoluted cases. Add `--tag-output` to the list of `mpiexec` arguments to make it prefix each output line with the job ID and rank ID it comes from so you don't have to print that information yourself.

Comment: Thank you for such an in depth answer! I ended up finally finding my mistake after hours of manual debugging, but I will definitely still need to know how to properly debug it later on. (I only fixed a small issue on one part out of several parts I need to write for the entire project). If I can't get GDB I will try and see if my adviser can get the university to buy a parallel debugger.

Comment: Thank you for this highly educational and pedagogically perfect post! I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 1):

For a command line only experience, you can have a look at [`tmpi`](https://github.com/Azrael3000/tmpi), which runs you MPI processes inside tmux panes (and multiplexes you keyboard input to each pane!)