# GDB debugger in MPI

Tags: gdb, fortran, mpi

I just do not know the command to run multiple processes using GDB. The following does not work.

```
r -np 64 ./a.out -gdb
```

Sorry this may seem quite simple. But I did not find much useful document about debugging in MPI using gdb from the Internet.

Comment: What is "r"? You need to use mpirun/mpiexec with most implementations. Try reading the OpenMPI FAQ entry on GDB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug an MPI program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329259/how-do-i-debug-an-mpi-program)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [OpenMPI documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers), you can start `xterm` through `mpirun`/`mpiexec` which then starts your program:

```
mpirun -np 64 xterm -e gdb ./a.out
```

This will open 64 windows, each containing a `gdb` session. As it will be quite cumbersome to enter `run` in each terminal, you could try

```
mpirun -np 64 xterm -e gdb ./a.out -ex run
```

However, I strongly recommend to reduce the number of processes used to, say, four.