# Broadcasting data read from file in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I am using MPI to parallelize a Brownian dynamics code. The code works perfectly when I initialize my particles on a lattice or in a clump. However, when I try to read in the initial conditions of my particles from a file (organized in columns containing x, y, and theta), then I get a segmentation fault. The function for reading in the data is:

```
void PlaceFromFile(){

  FILE *fp = fopen("init.config", "r");
  
  int i;
  
  for(i=0; i<= dyn.N-1; i++){
      
    fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf\n", &xx[i], &xy[i], &theta[i]);  

  }
  
  fclose(fp);
  
  fprintf(fp_log,"Initialised particle positions and orientations from file. \n");
  fflush(fp_log);
    
  return; 
}
```

The reading in part seems to go fine, the issue seems to arrise when I broadcast `xx`, `xy`, and `theta` as such:

```
void nb_expand(){

  int i, sendstart, sendend, sendnum;
  
  for (i = 0; i < nprocs; i++)
  {
  
    sendstart = (int)round(1.0*i/nprocs*dyn.N);
    sendend = (int)round(1.0*(i+1)/nprocs*dyn.N) - 1;
    sendnum = sendend - sendstart + 1;    
    
    MPI_Bcast(&xx[sendstart], sendnum, MPI_DOUBLE, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&xy[sendstart], sendnum, MPI_DOUBLE, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&theta[sendstart], sendnum, MPI_DOUBLE, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);        
  
  }
  
  return;
}
```

But I cannot figure out what the problem is. In my main code, I execute:

```
PlaceFromFile();
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);   
nb_expand();
```

I know that the segmentation fault somehow results from reading in my x, y, and theta values from a file. If I change the initialization to a triangular lattice instead and replace the `PlaceFromFile()` function with the following function:

```
void PlaceTriangular(){
  
  int i, k, p;
  double ax, ay;
  
  ax = dyn.Lx/(double)dyn.M;   // ax specifies the base of the triangle
  ay = dyn.Ly/(double)dyn.M;   // ay specifies the height of the triangle
  
  // place particles on a triangular lattice
  
  for(i=0;i<=dyn.N-1;i++){
    
    xx[i] = ax*i;
    xy[i] = 0.0;
        
    p = (int)(i*1.0/dyn.M);
    k = p % 2;
        
    if (i>dyn.M-1) {
        xx[i] = xx[i-dyn.M] + ax*0.5;
        if (k==0) xx[i] = xx[i] - ax;
        xy[i] = xy[i-dyn.M] + ay;
    } 
  
  }
  
  // assign random orientations to each particle
  
  for(i=0;i<=dyn.N-1;i++)
  {
    if ((i>=nstart) && (i<=nend)) {theta[i] = 2*M_PI*genrand64_real2();}
    else {theta[i] = 0.0;}
  }

  if (node == MASTER)
  {
    fprintf(fp_log,"Initialised particle positions and orientations. \n");
    fflush(fp_log);
  }   

  return;
}
```

everything works perfectly.

Comment: that's a lot of code, and still not enough code to reproduce. Here is some general advice: Tools to find segfaults are `valgrind` (works better with mpich than with openmpi), `gdb`, and `adress-sanitizer`/`memory-sanitizer` (compiler-plugins, works with clang). For the specific problem of data-reading: consider using hdf5, it is a library for reading/writing files with mpi, then you don't have to write any `scanf`-code

Comment: Even just the simple unix program `strace` is a lot better than just staring at your walls of code and hoping to find some revelation

Comment: This contains instructions for using `gdb`, the gnu debugger: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329259/how-do-i-debug-an-mpi-program?rq=2